# Pushnotfication not wroking with distributed profile

Tags: apple-push-notifications

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

I follow this link.push notification perfectly working with developement profile,successfully send and recieve notification But with distributed profile successfully send notificaition but not any receive notification on device.
And i noticed that my device token is different in this 2 profile.

Answer (score 0):

How do you think your device token is different? Push Notification will work if you make sure that create exactly Provisioning and you create app with AdHoc version where you added your UDID of your device.

Answer (score 0):

okay i got my mistake .when i used  distributed profile ,certificate for push notification i have to change gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com to gateway.push.apple.com 
and then it's woking:)